# Unable to break down "string.replace" in Python

Tags: python

I've been set a lab question for computer science and I'm really struggling to get to grips with it.. For the purposes of learning, we're not allowed to use "built-in" functions, namely "string.replace()" in this example..

I have defined a function to remove "stop-words" from input strings and cannot get it to work correctly, can anyone see any problems with what's going on below?

Cheers,

```
import string
text = raw_input ( " Please Enter Here: ")

def removePunctuation(text_input):
    line = []
    i = 0
    total_text = ""
    new_char_string = ""
    for char in text_input:
        if char in string.punctuation:
            char = ""

        new_char_string = new_char_string + char

    line = line + [new_char_string.lower()]
    total_text = (total_text + new_char_string).lower()
    return line
```

print removePunctuation(text)    <--- Fix for Friday...

```
def removeStopWords(text_input):
    line_stop_words = []
    stop_words = "a","It","i","it","am","at","on","in","of","to","is","so","too","my","The","the","and","but","are","very","here","even","from","them","then","than","this","that","though"
word = ""
for word in text_input:
    word_list = string.split(text_input)
    new_string = ""
    for word in word_list:
        if word in stop_words:
            new_string = new_string + word + " "
    new_string = string.split(new_string)
    line_stop_words = line_stop_words + [new_string]
return(line_stop_words)
```

print removeStopWords(text)

Comment: FYI, `word in stop_words` is potentially quite inefficient when stop_words is a tuple (as here); you should make it a set instead. (This may not be relevant for a short enough list, but since it's O(n), performance will get linearly worse as the list grows, whereas Python's set lookups are effectively constant-time).

Comment: First bug: `for word in text_input` is going to return *characters*, not *words*, if `text_input` is a string.

Comment: I'd strongly advise converting from a string to a (mutable) list at the beginning of your algorithm, making modifications to the list directly, and converting back to a string only at the end. String manipulation in Python is relatively expensive -- since strings are immutable, they can't be modified in-place -- so it's ideal to do just one big concatenation (as in `' '.join(words)`).

Comment: Another bug: `string.split(text)` should not work since `text` is not a variable here. Did you mean `string.split(word)`?

Comment: It would be really helpful to see a complete short program, exactly as you have run it on your machine, an example of an input line or file that's causing it to misbehave, and a description of what it's doing and what you'd expect it to do.

Comment: @qwrrty Thanks for the advice so far, I've changed the post to include the top half of the program, although it's not working too well...

Comment: why `line = line + [new_char_string.lower()]` instead of `line.append(new_char_string.lower())`?

Comment: @Eevee Afraid I can't use .append as a function... Pretty awkward :(

Comment: Seeing the program you're running is helpful, but this doesn't look like it can be the program you're actually running -- the indentation in removeStopWords is all wrong. @CharlesDuffy found an important clue. Here's another: when you test `if word in stop_words`, this code saves that word in new_string. But if the purpose is to remove words in stop_words, you want to do exactly the opposite.

Comment: @qwrrty quite right, just some botched copy/paste on my side :( and I can't believe i missed that! "not in" stop words... now just concatenation should fix. Great help, thanks